# Heroku: App name change caused SSL error

Tags: ssl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I know you're supposed to be able to piggyback off of Heroku's SSL, but when I changed my app name with:

`$ heroku rename newapp`

I get this SSL error when I view my app at https://newapp.herokuapp.com/

```
The certificate that Chrome received during this connection attempt is not formatted correctly, so Chrome cannot use it to protect your information.
Error type: Malformed certificate
Subject: *.herokuapp.com
Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
Public key hashes: sha1/oV2r98LTpC5d8oa283FuYG+1oaM= sha256/x2IS7dLWaSqiLbodu7k96NcxguyBN5Wvs7PjqvAqWuw= sha1/3lKvjNsfmrn+WmfDhvr2iVh/yRs= sha256/k2v657xBsOVe1PQRwOsHsw3bsGT2VzIqz5K+59sNQws= sha1/gzF+YoVCU9bXeDGQ7JGQVumRueM= sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=
```

I've changed an app name before and didn't have any SSL issues. Am I missing something simple? Or is this possibly just an issue with Heroku? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This error is only happening in my version of Chrome, and is fine on other browsers / devises.  Still haven't figured out how to fix it, but at least I know it's on my end and not Heroku's.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem today.  Try flushing your DNS.  If that doesn't work, go ahead and call your ISP.  It seems that they have some type of SSL/DNS cache that messes this type of thing up.

Hope this helps!

Alex